log4j2 cannot get any filters to work with consoleappender
Despite various searches showing example usage of a ConsoleAppender that contains filters, I find I get the following error if I put the Filter inside a Filters element inside the ConsoleAppender:
main ERROR appender Console has no parameter that matches element Filters

I get the following error if I put the Filter directly inside the ConsoleAppender:
main ERROR appender Console has no parameter that matches element RegexFilter

I am using this configuration, to try testing filtering out everything as a test:
        <Console name="PENTAHOCONSOLE">
            <ThresholdFilter level="INFO"/>
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Filters>
                <RegexFilter regex=".*" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            </Filters>
        </Console>

I am using version 2.17, and have the following jar files in my classpath:

log4j-1.2-api-2.17.1.jar
log4j-api-2.17.1.jar
log4j-core-2.17.1.jar
log4jdbc-1.2.jar
log4j-jcl-2.17.1.jar
log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.1.jar

Do I need a newer version for this to work?

An appender can only have a single filter configuration element. You already have ThresholdFilter, so any other filter will cause an error.
You need to put all filters in a composite filter (Filters).
<Filters>
  <ThresholdFilter level="INFO"/>
  <RegexFilter regex="..."/>
</Filters>

BTW: For better performance, filters should be added as early in the logging path as possible (in order global filters, <Logger> filters, <AppenderRef> filters).

Ok, that helped somewhat. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get the logging to make any useful changes. For example, if I put in the following:
    <Console name="PENTAHOCONSOLE">
        <Filters>
            <ThresholdFilter level="INFO"/>
        </Filters>
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>GIBBER %m%n ISH</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
    </Console>

No lines with GIBBER ever show up. I'm using Pentaho,  and wondering if it is doing some weird funky thing of its own.

Log4j Core is not the only logging backend for Java. Since most logging backends have a default configuration that uses the console, you can find the output of most of the on the console. If no lines contain GIBBER then either: 1. Log4j Core is not used. 2. That particular configuration files is not used. You can debug the latter by setting -Dlog4j2.debug.

Actually, the issue with the missing GIBBER is the product itself. When run as a UI, all logging config it ignored, and everything is logged. When run as a cli, the logging config takes effect.
